# How to get process details from its PID

Tags: go

I have maintained a list of PIDs of processes currently running on my system (Linux). From this, now it would be great if I could get the process details from this PID. I have come over syscall.Getrusage() in [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29), but I am not getting the desired results.

What should I do?

Comment: What results you are getting from `syscall.Getrusage`?

Comment: @Atom: see the Linux man page for `getrusage - get resource usage`.

Comment: for input 0x0 and 0x1 it is giving me some struct and i feel that this function can't be used to get process details and is for exclusive use by the one who started a process the problem with below code By peterSO is when i am reading process details of each pids i am getting for few processes no such dir exists as it may not present as process might have been killed completed its task.

Answer (score 173):

This might not be exactly what the asker wanted (there's not much clear info on what type of details are required for each process id), but you can get some details of a task by its pid using the BASH command `ps -p $PID` (*ps* being short for *process status*)

With default options as `ps -p $PID` this returns:

- PID: echos the process id
- TTY: the name of the controlling terminal (if any)
- TIME: how much CPU time the has process used since execution (e.g. 00:00:02)
- CMD: the command that called the process (e.g. `java`)

More information about this process id can be shown using the -o options flag. For a list, see [this documentation page](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/ps.1.asp#Format_Specifications).

Here's one example that tells you a particular process PID's full command with arguments, user, group and memory usage (note how the multiple -o flags each take a pair, and how the command outputs with lots of whitespace padding):

```
ps -p $PID -o pid,vsz=MEMORY -o user,group=GROUP -o comm,args=ARGS
```

Tip: for human-read output in the console, make args the last option - it'll usually be the longest and might get cut short otherwise.

Answer (score 59):

Just type this and you will get what you want. Replace 'type_PID_here' with the PID.

```
cat /proc/type_PID_here/status
```

Comment: Just in case, more information should be in `man proc`.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to see the path of the process by PID. You can use the `pwdx` command. The `pwdx` command reports the full path of the PID process.

```
$ pwdx 13896
13896: /home/user/python_program
```

**Note**: This method only works if you have the privilege to manage the process (ie. using the root user)

Comment: Yes, that can be slightly more enlightening than the output from `ps` or similar. Though it probably doesn't show where the executable lives (for instance, for a running Emacs installed from source with `make` (installed alongside another version installed by [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software))).

Comment: What do you mean by *"the path of process by PID"*? The [current working directory](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Working-Directory.html) (CWD)? That may not be the same as where the executable file lives.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the path of the process"* (now two instances)? What is it? The process' current working directory? Or something else?

Answer (score 28):

The shortest, and most effective option could be

```
ps -fp PID
```

it will return something like:

```
UID            PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
adam         78557    3688  0 Sep12 ?        00:00:07 /bin/python -m ipykernel_launcher -f /home/adam/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-aca88d6b.json
```

Answer (score 16):

```
ps -p PID -o comm=
```

Enter the code above where PID is PID of the process.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is it supposed to do? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43602118/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, Galeeb Basha seems to have left the building. Perhaps someone can chime in and edit (extend) this answer? Here is an [answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/632979/if-i-know-the-pid-number-of-a-process-how-can-i-get-its-name/632987#632987) that is slightly more detailed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I would gladly update the answer. Do you have something particular  in mind? Otherwise, I plan to complete the answer with what it prints, the `-o command` version and the same link to the documentation page. But the answer below seems better and already upvoted. Should not we simply forget about this one?

Answer (score 6):

You could look at `/proc/[pid]/stat`. For example, using Go 1,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func Pids() ([]int, error) {
    f, err := os.Open(`/proc`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    names, err := f.Readdirnames(-1)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    pids := make([]int, 0, len(names))
    for _, name := range names {
        if pid, err := strconv.ParseInt(name, 10, 0); err == nil {
            pids = append(pids, int(pid))
        }
    }
    return pids, nil
}

func ProcPidStat(pid int) ([]byte, error) {
    // /proc/[pid]/stat
    // https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html
    filename := `/proc/` + strconv.FormatInt(int64(pid), 10) + `/stat`
    return ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
}

func main() {
    pids, err := Pids()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("pids:", err)
        return
    }
    if len(pids) > 0 {
        pid := pids[0]
        stat, err := ProcPidStat(pid)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("pid:", pid, err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(`/proc/[pid]/stat:`, string(stat))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/proc/[pid]/stat: 1 (init) S 0 1 1 0 -1 4202752 11119 405425 21 57 78 92 6643 527 20 0 1 0 3 24768512 563 184467440737095
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the meaning of those numbers in the output from `/proc/44021/stat`? What is the general idea processing them? What is the principle of operation? Perhaps link to some *specific* documentation (not some high-level page). Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9380182/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

To get the details of the process using the ps command on terminal -

```
ps -Flww -p THE_PROCESS_PID
```

For more info, checkout the documentation on the man pages [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)