# How to know which process the class is running in?

Tags: android

Just for Android, for example `ActivityThread` could run in app process and system process, and `ActivityManagerService` is running in another, how could I know which process the class is running in.

Take the following scenario for example, `Context.startService` method is actually implemented by `ActivityManagerService.startService`, I want to know the detail, so I want to debug `ActivityManagerService`, but I don't know which process to debug, how can I know which process the `ActivityManagerService` is running in, and other class as well, I want to know how, not what.

Comment: Please outline what you are trying to do, Android is a unix based system, see also whoami

Comment: Its PID? what are you trying to do where the PID does not give you the user? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378021/how-to-get-process-details-from-its-pid/13780824 I propose that as the answer to this question in its current form and I move to close this question as a duplicate with only 1 point of bounty.

Comment: @Jay   Sometimes I need to debug in some system class, only if I know which process the class is running in, I could set the debug the right process.

Comment: @Jay It's not about pid，I update the question.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55842542/13121971

Comment: @UrbanR No, this is used in the code that I can modify

Comment: even if you can get the id of this process you can not simply debug it as it's not yours and not built in debug mode

Comment: @MuhannadFakhouri I'd agree... there seems to be some misconception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some ways, read the source code, and find the manifest of the apk, but this will only work for code under `packages` dir